# How to return a list of objects using MappingSqlQuery

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, mapping

I have the following class which has to return the list of objects

```
private class getOfficeNumberQuery extends MappingSqlQuery<OfficeNumberVO>
    {
        private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(GetAccruedBalanceForAssociateQuery.class);

        static private final String SQL = " SELECT b.xxxx AS associateMasterRecordId,a.zzz AS accruedHour, offices.yyy AS officeNumber  "
                + " FROM table3  a, table1 b, table2 offices WHERE a.Aident = b.Aident AND offices.branchId = b.branchId AND (a.AvailableBalance <> 0.0000 OR a.AvailableBalance <> null) "
                + " AND offices.BranchName IN(?)) ";

        public getOfficeNumberQuery(DataSource ds)
        {
            super(ds, SQL.toString());
            super.declareParameter(new SqlParameter("BranchName", Types.VARCHAR));

            try
            {
                compile();
            }
            catch (InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException e)
            {
                log.error("getOfficeNumberQuery(DataSource)", e); //$NON-NLS-1$

                throw new StaffTrackSystemFailureException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected OfficeNumberVO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException
        {
            OfficeNumberVO payInfo = new OfficeNumberVO() ;

            payInfo.setAssociateMasterRecordId(rs.getLong("associateMasterRecordId"));
            payInfo.setAccruedHour(rs.getLong("accruedHour"));
            payInfo.setOfficeNumber(rs.getString("officeNumber"));

            return payInfo;
        }

    }
```

How to modify this method to return List of objects

```
@Override
            protected OfficeNumberVO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException
            {
                OfficeNumberVO payInfo = new OfficeNumberVO() ;

                payInfo.setAssociateMasterRecordId(rs.getLong("associateMasterRecordId"));
                payInfo.setAccruedHour(rs.getLong("accruedHour"));
                payInfo.setOfficeNumber(rs.getString("officeNumber"));

                return payInfo;
            }
```

Also would someone help me whether the SQL written is fine?

Environment : SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT b.xxxx AS associateMasterRecordId,
 a.zzz AS accruedHour, offices.yyy AS officeNumber
 FROM table3 a JOIN table1 b ON a.Aident = b.Aident
 JOIN table2 offices ON offices.branchId = b.branchId
 WHERE a.AvailableBalance <> 0.0000 OR a.AvailableBalance is not null
 AND offices.BranchName IN(?)
```

There were a few changes made to your SQL. Firstly, ANSI SQL `join` syntax was used. And `<> null` condition in the `where` clause has been replaced with `is not null`.